# importing django models into another application

Tags: python, django, database

I have my django web site pretty functional, it talks to the database and to the web clients.  I have my folders set up like this:

```
top
+--- django
     +---my_framework
         +--- models.py
         +--- settings.py
     +---lib
+--- scripts
     +---scripts_that_do_stuff_from_console
     +--- service_that_needs_access_to_models
```

I have been able to access the libraries in the lib folders from the different scrips in my scripts folder like this:

```
lib_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.join('..', 'django'),"lib"))
sys.path.append(lib_path)
```

This doesn't seem very elegant, but it works.

I need another application that runs in the background that talks to the database and supports the django framework and interacts with the console.
I want to access some models in my models.py, so I tried this:

```
lib_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.join('..', 'django'),"lib"))
sys.path.append(lib_path)
from models import SystemConfiguration
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./imageHandler.py", line 14, in <module>
    from models import SystemConfiguration
  File "/home/jordan/django/my_framework/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.middleware.csrf import rotate_token
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/cache.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import caches
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I understand that the script needs to read the settings.py so I tried:

```
import settings as mySettings
settings.configure(default_settings=mySettings, DEBUG=True)
```

which didn't really help. I have poked at this for a while but have not been able make any headway.  Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Getting somewhere better....  I added this (as Semprini suggested):

```
lib_path = os.path.abspath("/mnt/garageMonitor/django/lib")
sys.path.append(lib_path)
lib_path = os.path.abspath("/mnt/garageMonitor/django/garageMonitor")
sys.path.append(lib_path)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
from models import SystemConfiguration
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Unable to detect the app label for model "MyClass." Ensure that its module, "models", is located inside an installed app.
```

MyClass is located in the models.py file, so it is now opening it correctly but there are other errors...

Answer (score 1):

The settings module needs to be added to the os.environ dict at the start (probably before you import any models but after you do your sys.path.append)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

Folder layout:

```
Wibble Project>
   manage.py
   wibble>
      settings.py   #must contain 'stuff' as an app
   stuff>
      models.py
   test.py
```

Sample test.py:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'wibble.settings'
from stuff.models import MyObject
print(MyObject.objects.all())
```

Output:

```
python test.py
```

`[<MyObject: Object1>,<MyObject: Object2>]`

Comment: Getting somewhere better....  I added this:>`lib_path = os.path.abspath("/mnt/garageMonitor/django/lib")
sys.path.append(lib_path)
lib_path = os.path.abspath("/mnt/garageMonitor/django/garageMonitor")
sys.path.append(lib_path)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
from models import SystemConfiguration
>Now I am getting this error:django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Unable to detect the app label for model "MyClass." Ensure that its module, "models", is located inside an installed app.
MyClass is located in the models.py file